# setText method of class TextView throws unexplained exception

Tags: java, android, exception, textview

I wrote Android client.
The class ClientThread implements Runnable interface, this is the run method:

ClientThread.java

```
 public void run() {
   connect(); //connects the server

   String msg = ""; //holds the msg recieved from server
   try {
      while(connected && (msg = br.readLine())!= null)
      {
         //System.out.println("Server:"+msg);
          if (!msg.isEmpty())
              creatingActivity.displayServerAnswer("Server:"+msg);

         //notify observers//
         this.setChanged();
        //notify+send out recieved msg to Observers
         this.notifyObservers(msg);
      }
   }
   catch(IOException ioe) { }
   finally { disconnect(); connected = false; }
  }
```

The purpose was to display the server answer on the device screen.

MainActivity.java

```
    public void displayServerAnswer(String answer){
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);
        try {
            textView.setText(answer);
        }
        catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

From some reason when `textView.setText(answer);` is called an exception is thrown. I don't know of which kind. before I wrapped the line with try-catch block the program stopped the running.
Now I catch the exception and do nothing. **Even the exception is thrown the text is set**.
So how can I find out what is this exception?

**EDIT:**
As was mentioned in the comments, by checking the exception object message field:

> Only the original thread that created view hirarchy can touch its
>   views

So now I understand the exception but I don't understand why it was thrown only in the second time, the client thread called `creatingActivity.displayServerAnswer("Server:"+msg);`

Comment: logcat is very useful. I imagine the issue is probably that the TextView has not been created yet.

Comment: Run your app in debug configuration and examine the exception in the debugger when it gets thrown.

Comment: You are trying to modify the UI from a different thread. You can only do that from the UI thread. Use a Handler to achieve that

Comment: @Kushtrim : I also thought about this, but the thing is that in the first time the text is set, no exception thrown. only from the second time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  public void displayServerAnswer(String answer){
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);
    try {
        textView.setText(answer);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You are catching the exception but not diong anything with it. Printing a stack trace will show you which line of code caused the exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are setting the text from background thread in run method .
Use runonUithread or handler to change the text.inside run method.:)